# Apache Pig UDF Resolution Issue

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I've got the following Java code (returns fixed value for testing):

### Static.java

```
package com.company;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.impl.util.WrappedIOException;

public class Static extends EvalFunc<String>
{
        public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException
        {
                if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
                    return null;
                try
                {
                        String str = (String)input.get(0);
                        return "5876L";
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                        throw WrappedIOException.wrap("Caught exception processing input row ", e);
                }
        }
}
```

### Built using

```
javac -Xbootclasspath:/usr/lib/jvm/j2sdk1.6-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar -source 1.6 -cp `hadoop classpath`:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.3.0-1.cdh4.3.0.p0.22/lib/pig/pig-0.11.0-cdh4.3.0.jar Static.java

jar -cf Static.jar Static.class
```

### Apache Pig job

```
REGISTER /path/to/Static.jar;

loaded = LOAD 'data/' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.store.LzoPigStorage() AS (line:chararray);

loaded = SAMPLE loaded 0.00001;

sized = FOREACH loaded GENERATE com.company.Static(line);

DUMP sized;
```

### Is ran with

```
# pig -f static.pig -x local
```

### Which errors

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve com.company.Static using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
```

### Changing the line

```
sized = FOREACH loaded GENERATE com.company.Static(line);
```

### To

```
sized = FOREACH loaded GENERATE Static(request);
```

### It errors with

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. Static (wrong name: com/company/Static)
```

Comment: Yea, sorry. It's consistently com.company across the board. I missed that package name when I was sanitizing the code. Could you remove your reference as well?

Comment: Can you try `DEFINE Static com.company.Static();` and then use `Static` to call the UDF? Does that work?

Comment: [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve com.company.Static using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be missing the required directory structure in the jar. `com.company.Static` (i.e., the `Static.class` file) should be located under the `com/company` directory in the jar. See this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355407/jar-main-class-not-found-problem) for more details.

For more details, see my response to [this other question you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124179/pig-error-2998-unhandled-internal-error-static-wrong-name-com-company-static).